# Why can't I make a GET request to flickr api but I the request works when all the parameters are embedded in the string?

Tags: api, rest, get, flickr

I'm trying to make a request to the Flickr api using two methods:

1. Directly going to 
   http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=KEYHERE&text=lol
2. Going to http://www.requestmaker.com and setting the URL to http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/ and setting appropriate values for headers api_key, text and method.

The second method never works, but the first method does. I'm ensuring the request is a GET request. Any idea why?

I also tried other similar sites for #2 and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used requestmaker until now, but I just tried and it works for me. I'm guessing your input is incorrect - try one of these two methods:

- are you using requestmaker GET or POST method (it's the top-right dropdown)?

  - if GET, then 
     
    Request URL: `http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/? method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=KEYHERE&text=lol`
    Request Header: `Leave as is`
    Request Data: `N/A (you're using GET so nothing to post)`
  - if POST, then
    Request URL: `http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/`
    Request Header: `N/A (remove the headers)`
    Request Data: `method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=KEYHERE&text=lol`